# Logrotate is not working centos 6.6

Tags: centos, logging, log-files, logrotate, log-rotation

I have the following configuration for logrotating the app logs.

```
/opt/tomcat/logs/app-web.txt {
    copytruncate
    daily
    size 500M
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 0
    missingok
    notifempty
}

/opt/tomcat/logs has a lot of files


app-web.txt
app-web.txt.1
app-web.txt.2
app-web.txt.3
app-web.txt.4
..
..
..
..
..
app-web.txt.100
```

I have placed the configuration inside /etc/logrotate.d/app-web. I am running CentOs 6.6

**I want to have 9 files only like aap-web.txt and app-web.txt.1.gz to app-web.txt.9.gz**

Each file inside /opt/tomcat/logs are of 498 M of size. and they are created every 1 hour 30 min.

```
 $cat /var/lib/logrotate.status
```

displays the time that I ran manually. It doesn't run automatically by cron.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> rotate 0
> ```

from the man page

> **rotate count**
>   Log files are rotated count times before being removed or mailed to the address specified in a mail directive. If count is 0, old versions are removed rather than rotated.

You probably want

```
rotate 9
```

As to why you are seeing all the other files, my guess is that they are old (check the date/time) and logrotate is not considering them because they do not match the name *app-web.txt*. I would just archive those I needed for the relevant period and then delete them. I would then expect logrotate to start managing the files as expected.

Note that generally cron is configured to run logrotate just once per day ( /etc/cron.dailylogrotate). If you want to rotate the files based on size and that size is reached more frequently than once a day you will need to run logrotate more frequently.